# Adding date() with suffix to sqlite3 query

Tags: bash, sqlite

Looking to replace the 2017-02-14 part of the code with yesterdays date as a function as I want to be able to use this query without having to modify it daily. I tried adapting other code found in the forums but wasn't getting anywhere.

I'm searching a database trying to find the time when a specific event started on the previous day which is where the like expression and underscores become necessary. I tried to use the date() function of sqlite3 but couldn't find a way to add the "__ __ __" suffix to be able to find the specific entry.

Additionally I'm not familiar enough with bash to be able to pass `date +'%Y-%m-%d'` to the query and add the "__ __ __" suffix to the end of it as well to be able to find the entry I'm looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash 
yesterday=$(date -d yesterday +'%Y-%m-%d __:__:__')                  
startDetails=sqlite3 hub.db 'select substr(timestamp,12,19) 
                              from OET where entryID="0" 
                               and timestamp like "2017-02-14 __:__:__";' 
stopDetails=sqlite3 hub.db 'select substr(timestamp,12,19) 
                             from OET where entryID="5" 
                              and timestamp like "'"$yesterday"'";' 

echo "Start: " $startDetails "Finish: "$stopDetails 
exit 0 
fi
```

I've copied in a simplified form of what I'm trying to do. In its current state the first query returns correctly, listing the two start times for the day, however, the second query returns nothing, running this script in debug returns the following results.

```
+ $'\r'
checkWebID.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
++ date -d yesterday '+%Y-%m-%d __:__:__'
' yesterday='2017-02-14 __:__:__
++ sqlite3 hub.db 'select substr(timestamp,12,19) 
                    from OET where entryID="0" 
                     and timestamp like "2017-02-15 __:__:__";'
+ Details='04:49:01
'4:07:42
";'sqlite3 hub.db 'select substr(timestamp,12,19) 
                    from OET where entryID="5" 
                     and timestamp like "2017-02-14 __:__:__
+ StopDetails=$'\r'
+ $'\r'
checkWebID.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
+ echo 'Start: ' 04:49:01 $'14:07:42\r' 'Finish: ' $'\r\r'
 Finish:  :49:01 14:07:42
+ exit $'0\r'
: numeric argument required: 0
```

Comment: The error messages with `$'\r'` in them indicate that you've been playing with a Windows machine and your script contains CRLF (DOS-style) line endings instead of Unix-like NL (LF) line endings.  Fix the file format to work as Unix, not DOS (in Vim, `:set fileformat=unix` would probably do the job; there are many other ways to do that, and numerous questions on SO where changing the line ending is the relevant fix.

Comment: Using the command dos2unix, I was able to convert the file format from DOS to Unix, running the script now returns the desired results. Thanks for your help, you saved me having to trudge through a lot of mud. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using GNU `date`, it might be as simple as:

```
yesterday=$(date -d yesterday +'%Y-%m-%d __:__:__')
startDetails=`sqlite3 hub.db 'select substr(timestamp,12,19)
                                from OET where entryID="0"
                                 and timestamp like "'"$yesterday"'";'`
```

The quotes have to be carefully orchestrated.  In the fragment:

```
'select … like "'"$yesterday"'";'
```

the first double quote is a literal; the next single quote terminates the single-quoted string; the `"$yesterday"` encloses the value in the shell variable `yesterday` in double quotes (those quotes are not optional because of the space in the value of `$yesterday` — but you could change things so that they are optional); then the single quote starts (resumes) a single quoted string, the double quote is part of the string, and then the single quote ends the single-quoted string again.

In general, you should use the `$(…)` notation in preference to backticks, especially if you plan to discuss things in MarkDown (but there are technical reasons to prefer `$(…)` independently of SO and MarkDown).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, cleared up the practice, however, it hasn't quite worked. I am using GNU/linux Ubuntu 11.04

I have updated original question.

Comment: The first step in debugging is printing — in this case, probably use `sh -x yourscript.sh` to see what is in `$yesterday` (for me, on 2017-02-14T19:15:37, the `date -d yesterday +'%Y/%m/%d __:__:__'` command produced `2017/02/13 __:__:__`, which is what was wanted.  Did you get the equivalent?  You've also managed to lose the back-ticks in your commands — is that a transcription error when you updated the question?  (Also, you should generally not remove the original material from the question once you've got answers.  You did preserve (more or less) enough of the original, but be cautious!)

Comment: I note that your running text and the original version of the question uses `2017/02/14` and the revised query uses `2017-02-14` — choose the one that works, and fix the value saved in `$yesterday` to match. It's a simple change of the format string for `date`.  Revisions 1 and 2 of your SQL used the `/` notation; revisions 3 and 4 use the `-` notation. Choose your poison, but don't try mixing them. Of course, it is possible that both notations work. You're also using double quotes around strings in the SQL; standard SQL requires single quotes there, but I'm used to RDBMS that aren't as fussy.

Comment: Sorry that was naturally how I write dates, it should be correct now, I want the date format to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` additionally, don't mind the different dates 2017-02-15 & 2017-02-14

Again you're right I did lose the back-ticks when copying from the terminal to here, they are present in the script and seem to be doing what they need to do. Will keep that in mind for future reference thanks.

The source code I have been using for reference all uses double quotes and it doesn't seem to be impacting it, will do some research on that though.